# Error 200000,blank page and sign in failed in Tableau Server

Tags: tableau-api

why Tableau server 9.0 Show Error 200000? or Blank Page?

Server Info:
Ram:32G
Sqlserver 2012
Drive 332G free
Database 70G

Tableau Service is run. and it's work for 30min then show blank page or sign in failed then I have to reset tableau service after 30 min tableau is correct then repeat again this process!!! I usually reset tableau service 5times in a day.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many cores do you have on this machine, and which specific version of 9.0 is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you have provided, it seems the tableau server is not running.

Please verify whether the tableau server is running by typing the following in command prompt with admin privilege

tabadmin status

it will show whether the tableau server is running or not. If its running please open the tableau server portal in Google Chrome/Internet Explorer by typing localhost: something like localhost:8000

this will open admin portal if server is running. under maintenance please check whether everything is running like the one shown below.

[image: Tableau Server]

Also please check whether the firewall is blocking the tableau server.

Comment: very Thank you for your reply. Tableau Service is run. and it's work for 30min then show blank page or sign in failed then I have to reset tableau service. after 30 min tableau is correct then repeat again this process!!! I usually reset tableau service many times in a day.

Comment: my tableau version is 9.0 and I login admin user. but I don't have Maintenance Item.  Where is it in ver 9.0?

Comment: http://<servername>/#/server/status is where you can find the 9.0 and 9.1 equivalent of the Maintenance page

Comment: Thank you. I used this address: http://<servername>/#/server/status but after login show "That page could not be accessed.
Either it does not exist, or you do not have the necessary permissions.
' this error.

Comment: Hi Can you tell me what type of access you have for the tableau server.